# React cli fails to run app on device, but runs from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

When I run my react-native app from Xcode to my iPhone it runs successfully. When I run from react cli to my device, the app suddenly stops, without giving a specific error.

Comment: is there any log ?

Comment: @EneaDume nope, not at all. Even with the js debugger on, it doesn't show any error.